# Caching URL Elements for Faster Loading in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview

I'm attempting to load a URL (A Product Page) in a UIWebView as fast as possible. The problem is that product always changes on reload (random) so I was wondering if there was any way that I could cache the other elements of the page (menu bar, button images, etc) so that everytime I display the url, at least those parts of the page load fast. The site is http://tinyurl.com/kszlfug